# Spring query with a one to many param

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I must query network elements that have some parameters similiar to the given values, for instance searching for "xampleV" will return  rows with "ExampleValue".

This is currently working, except for the port parameter which is mapped one to many in network element.

```
@Entity
public class NetworkElement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    /**
     * The ip address of the NetworkElement. This should be unique
     */
    public String ip;

    /**
     * The port or NetworkElement
     */
    public int port;

    /**
     * The name this node is called. This is what the user want to see on the Gui for such NetworkElement
     */
    public String name;

    /**
     * Timestamp of the last alarm received for this NetworkElement
     */
    public long lastEventTimestamp;

    /**
     * Last read index from the alarm status table
     */
    public int lastReadIndex;

    public long latitude;

    public long longitude;

    public String address;

    public String upTime;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "node")
    public List<Port> ports;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    public NetworkElementType networkElementType;

    public NetworkElement(String ip, String name, long lastEventTimestamp, List<Port> ports, NetworkElementType networkElementType) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastEventTimestamp = lastEventTimestamp;
        this.ports = ports;
        this.networkElementType = networkElementType;
    }


}
```

This is what my query looks like in NetworkElementRepository

```
    @Query("SELECT ne FROM NetworkElement ne WHERE " +
        "ne.ip LIKE %:ip% AND " +
        "str(ne.port) LIKE %:port% AND " +
        "lower(ne.name) LIKE concat('%', lower(:name), '%') AND " +
        "lower(ne.networkElementType.type) LIKE concat('%', lower(:type), '%') AND " +
        "lower(ne.networkElementType.vendor) LIKE concat('%', lower(:vendor), '%') AND " +
        "lower(ne.networkElementType.version) LIKE concat('%', lower(:version), '%') AND "+
        "lower(ne.networkElementType.port) LIKE concat('%', lower(:customerId), '%')")

List<NetworkElement> search(
        @Param("ip") String ip, @Param("port") String port,
        @Param("name") String name,@Param("vendor") String vendor,
        @Param("type") String type, @Param("version") String version, @Param("customerId") String customerId);
```

This clearly isn't correct as port is not a single value but a list.

Here's the Port class

```
@Entity
public class Port {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public NetworkElement node;

    public String type;
    /**
     * Id of the rack (may be null)
     */
    public String rack;
    /**
     * Id of the frame
     */
    public String frame;
    /**
     * Id of the card slot
     */
    public String slot;
    /**
     * Serial of the port
     */
    public String portSerial;

    public String customerId;

    public long esThresholdUp;
    public long esThresholdDown;
    public long sesThresholdUp;
    public long sesThresholdDown;

    public PortStatus status;

    /**
     * Timestamp of the last event for this port
     */
    public long lastEventTimestamp;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Port{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", node=" + node +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", rack='" + rack + '\'' +
                ", frame='" + frame + '\'' +
                ", slot='" + slot + '\'' +
                ", portSerial='" + portSerial + '\'' +
                ", customerId='" + customerId + '\'' +
                ", esThresholdUp=" + esThresholdUp +
                ", esThresholdDown=" + esThresholdDown +
                ", sesThresholdUp=" + sesThresholdUp +
                ", sesThresholdDown=" + sesThresholdDown +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

How do I query network elements that have ports with a specific customerId correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Port` entity value is called `customerId`, like:

```
@Entity
class Port {
    private Integer customerId;
}
```

You need a new `JOIN` and a change on `WHERE`:

```
@Query("SELECT ne FROM NetworkElement ne JOIN ne.ports port WHERE " +
    "ne.ip LIKE %:ip% AND " +
    "lower(ne.name) LIKE concat('%', lower(:name), '%') AND " +
    "lower(ne.networkElementType.type) LIKE concat('%', lower(:type), '%') AND " +
    "lower(ne.networkElementType.vendor) LIKE concat('%', lower(:vendor), '%') AND " +
    "lower(ne.networkElementType.version) LIKE concat('%', lower(:version), '%') AND "+
    "port.customerId LIKE concat('%', lower(:customerId), '%')")`
```

And delete the `@Param("port") String port`.

Comment: The entity Port has a field called customerId that must be matched. This means that the last row in your code should beremoved, and that   "str(port.value) LIKE %:port% AND " + should be 
  "str(port.customerId) LIKE %:customerId% AND " +

is that right?

Comment: Yes! I will change my answer, I not see the last line

Comment: Shouldn't you still remove port.value ? I'm asking just to be sure :)

Comment: Right, removed.

Comment: I tried this: 
  @Query("SELECT ne FROM NetworkElement ne " +
            "JOIN ne.ports port" +
            "WHERE " +
            "ne.ip LIKE %:ip% AND " +
            "lower(ne.name) LIKE concat('%', lower(:name), '%') AND " +
            "lower(ne.networkElementType.type) LIKE concat('%', lower(:type), '%') AND " +
            "lower(ne.networkElementType.vendor) LIKE concat('%', lower(:vendor), '%') AND " +
            "lower(ne.networkElementType.version) LIKE concat('%', lower(:version), '%') AND "+
            "lower(port.customerId) LIKE concat('%', lower(:customerId), '%')")

Comment: Show your Port class in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165906/discussion-between-pierangelo-calanna-and-dherik).

Comment: I modified my question